# Why doesn't Barbara witness any change in her eye sight?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-1984

After wishing by touching a stone to become strong like Diana, Barbara wakes up and
goes to mirror to check. Why doesn't Barbara witness any change in eye sight?

[image]

[Peter Parker](https://youtu.be/kP8KWVsXK3k?t=78) eye sight improved after spider bite, why not
here?

Comment: Physical strength has nothing to do with eye sight, and as you said Peter's change was due to radioactivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Barbara's eyesight *did* improve.

In a later scene (just before Diana introduces her to Steve Trevor), Barbara said her eyesight had been cured, and stopped wearing glasses from that point forward.

> BARBARA: So I did read about four books last night... to try to get to the bottom of this. And I did find out, Roger, you were right. This is from the Song Dynasty. You were correct. And also interesting, I was looking at a couple of encyclopedias last night and you... Thanks. Um... **So funny, all this reading seems to have cured my eyesight somehow.**
>
> <sub>*Wonder Woman 1984*</sub>

As for why she didn't notice it in the earlier scene, perhaps the changes to her strength and eyesight occurred gradually over time, rather than all in one go.